# Send HTTP POST - Android

Tags: java, android, json, url, http-post

I know that this has been asked but most are out dated, and method are deprecated. I have found this solution,

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String query = "param=" +"item"+"&other="+"num";

                URL url = new URL("http://www.url.com/url_post.php");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                //Set to POST
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
                Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

But, it does not provide how to get data that is returned for example, I am return some JSON, where get I get that data that is returned?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: if you can use OutputStream to write, then you shouldn't you try to use InputStream to read

Comment: @JunedAhsan I don't use InputStream?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
 //Get Response 
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  String line;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
  while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(line);
    response.append('\r');
```

Finally in response you will get response JSON string then do what you want to do.

For more details visit this link
http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

Comment: Thanks, just checking I should do this inside the `try` correct?

Comment: what do you mean cause any exception?

Comment: I mean if we are doing any IO operation then also need to take care about Exception

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use this project as library:

https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

It's extremely easy and I use it for all my projects. I commited it to Github because it is difficult for me to find an easy Rest client for general purpose.

I'm going to commit an update for integration with Android Studio ASAP.

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this part after your writer.close()

```
 connection.connect();
        int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("ON POST", " The status code is " + statusCode);

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            String response = convertInputStreamToString(is);
            Log.d("ON POST", "The response is " + response);

            return response;

        } else {
            Log.d("ON POST", "On Else");
            return "";
        }
```

The ConvertInputStreamToString() should be created to return your json as string

```
public static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream in) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```